# What is the best word that defines the space shown in this picture?

Tags: single-word-requests

American Heritage Dictionary defines:

> [plaza](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=plaza&submit.x=46&submit.y=17):
>   a public square or similar open area in a town or city.
>
> [gallery](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=gallery&submit.x=45&submit.y=19):
>   a roofed promenade, especially one extending along the wall of a
>   building and supported by arches or columns on the outer side.

Which is the better word defining the space shown in the picture below: "plaza" or "gallery"? Or is there a more appropriate word?

[image]

Comment: @simchona - Thank you for having edited the question.

Comment: "appropriated" is a valid word, but it refers to taking something for yourself

Comment: What city is this located in?

Comment: @Mitch: I don't know. I incidentally found the picture in The New York Times while I was searching for grammatical forms.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect this kind of thing varies a lot by speaker. I upvoted both "colonnade" and "covered walkway" because those are the two things it occurred to me to call the structure in the photo; I've personally never heard such things called "arcades" in speech, only in writing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps, the word [**arcade**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arcade) would do.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps 'covered walkway' would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

A colonnade is ["a structure composed of columns placed at regular intervals."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colonnade)

A colonnade at the Acropolis:

[image]

Comment: This was the first word I thought of when I saw the picture.

Answer (score 4):

It may also be called a ***mall***: 
 <sub>( *see esp. 2 and 3)*</sub>

> [***mall***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mall)
>   *n.
>
>   1. A large, often enclosed shopping complex containing various stores, businesses, and restaurants usually accessible by common passageways.
>
>   2. A street lined with shops and closed to vehicles.
>
>   3. A shady public walk or promenade.*

Edit:
*[Here is a link](http://www.bearcanada.com/diary/shanghaidiary13.html) refering to OP's exact place as a* **pedestrian mall** *(scroll down for a section labeled* "Maybe the Largest LED Screen in the World"

Answer (score 2):

In British English the word **parade** is often used for an open walking area, whether covered or not. http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parade offers the description *a public square or promenade.*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I voted up, but I would suggest you to provide a link to "parade". For example: definition n. 6 in American Heritage Dictionary "6. A public square or promenade."

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, I suppose it would be called a *pedestrianised zone*.

Comment: In AmE, this would be _pedestrian zone_.